# Trouble getting jQuery Validation plugin to work

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I'm new to jQuery and, although I understand the gist of how it works, I'm unable to figure out why the validation plugin isn't working on my form.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type=text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#signup").validate();
    });
</script>
```

Form Header:

```
<form action="/registration/" method="post" id="signup">
```

Furthermore, what are the recommended sources for getting the latest versions of both jQuery and the validate plugin?

Comment: Using ajax.googleapis.com is the simplest way to get jQuery. You probably shouldn't point directly to github.com for the validate plugin, you should download it to your own site. Regarding why it's not working, you need to show us the form fields in your HTML and tell us what kind of validation you're expecting it to do.

Comment: I did download the plugin from the developer's site, however I wasn't sure which file to include in the script. Is it the one called 'grunt.js'? The fields in my form are just standard text/password/email fields. For now I just want it to perform the default validation until I get a chance to play around with the rules for it.

Comment: There is no "default validation". You need to add rules, either by attributes in the HTML markup or by parameters to the "validate" function. Also, if you want to perform the validation right away (before clicking on "submit" or doing any action), call the `form` function of the validator, like this: `$("#signup").validate().form();`

Comment: You need to include `jquery.validate.js` or `jquery.validate.min.js`, not "grunt.js".

Comment: I've update my code as suggested. So in order to produce results, I need to add rules for the plugin to actually function? That is, it won't do anything right now, given the code as it is above?

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly. Rules are necessary for the plugin to produce results.

Answer (score 1):

The file you need to download is called 'jquery.validate.js'.

By default, the validation plugin uses the classes of the input fields for validation. So if you have an email field, use:

```
<input type="text" class="email" />
```

If a field is required, add `required` to the class, e.g.:

```
<input type="text" class="required" />
```

If it's a required email, combine them:

```
<input type="text" class="required email" />
```

It also understands HTML5 input types and attributes, so you could do:

```
<input type="email" required="required"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify rules for the validator. You also need to click the "submit" button to perform the validation. Alternatively, you may want to trigger the validation using the `form` function of the Validator object (which is not usually recommended).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script type=text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#signup").validate({rules: {'company': 'required'}}).form();
    });
</script>

<form action="/registration/" method="post" id="signup">
    Company: <input type="text" name="company" />
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Comment: As I said... it is better to trigger the validation by clicking the submit button (the plugin performs the validation when you do it), instead of calling the `form` function. I am just using it for the sample code to work "out of the box"...

Comment: What is the purpose of {'name': 'required'} as a parameter of validate()?

Comment: Sorry, it needs to be the "rules" option... just corrected it. It is a simple rule: it means the "name" field is required.

Comment: Is it the field with `name="name"` or with `class="name"`?

Comment: Indeed, the example was confusing. I changed it, so your doubt will be answered... The left-side of each rule must be the field name, i.e., it must match the input `name` attribute: `<input name="fieldname">`. The right-side can be one of the built-in validation rules of the plugin ("required", "email", "digits" and others) or a custom one, or even a set of rules (in this case, you need an object, instead of a string)...